# A429 label 044, DME Identity Presence - Definition

Tags: arinc-429

Is there a bit by bit definition for the A429 label 044, DME Identity Presence?

I have this label 044 coming out of a Collins DME-4000, but it is not defined in its documentation I have at hand (installation manual). Only distance, IDENT, tune echo, etc. are defined.

Now, since this label is there, I'm interested what its contents are, this is not a standard label defined in the A429 specification. Hence my question: *Is there a bit by bit definition for the A429 label 044, DME Identity Presence?*

I know from a different installation manual at least that the label is used for "DME Identity Presence". I was just hoping the keywords "label 044" and "DME Identity Presence" rings a bell for someone who then would kindly provide a bit by bit definition from a source that I just don't have (or at least haven't found, yet).

Comment: That particular label description doesn't show up in my copy of ARINC 429. It may be in a newer version or in the installation or equipment manuals for the DME-4000 if it is a custom designed label. It should at least be a BCD label, so I would probably start there.

Comment: Thanks @selectstriker2! I have hands on a CMM of the DME, but it isn't mentioned even there. I feel lucky that at least in some documentation I found the definition "DME Identity Presence" so that at least I have a hint for the direction to look for. So far, without success.

Comment: I can't answer the specific question, but can provide some insight. The Proline 21 radios were designed to handle a wide variation of configurations. To 'simplify' installations, there was an option to connect the radios to an RIU-4x00 (radio interface unit), which then connected to controls, displays, and other systems. To make it all work, there were a number of ARINC 429 labels that were added and some remapped so they could be combined on a single bus. The RIU handled most of it internally. I expect the label you're seeing provides configuration information to the RIU.

Comment: Thanks for that insight! Yes, I can confirm there are a lot more labels on the bus which are not documented. Since I only found at least a description for label 044 (DME Intentity Presence) I thought I give it a try and ask here if somenbody knows something about it. In the end, I would like to display something in the IDENT Area of the Proline 21 PFD. But I figured, sending the documented label 300 is not sufficient. So I thought label 044 will do the trick. Which it didn't...